# What firmware file format uses the header "Intel_FBF"

Tags: embedded, intel

I'm trying to identify a file, but it has a header I've never seen before: "Intel_FBF". It's likely an embedded firmware file, but I have no idea.

Comment: If you want us to identify the file format then please post a sample section of it as part of the question.  I assume that it is an ASCII format.  Post a few lines from the start and end and maybe any interesting bits from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's not much information to go by. Can you give any other hints about its history, context?

- Is it binary, text?
- What is the file name, extension?
- Where did it come from?
- What were you told it's good for?

One thing you could try is the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility on Linux.